# Parse - change user that is not the current user

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to change an user that is not the current user with the following code

```
  let query = PFQuery(className:"_User")

        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(userId) {
            (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            print("UPDATE THIS USER->\(object)")

            if error != nil
            {
                print("COULD NOT CHANGE REPUTATION \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }
            else if let object = object
            {
                object.incrementKey("reputation", byAmount: value)
                object.saveEventually({ (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    print("USER REPUTATION CHANGE SUCCEDDED? ->\(succeeded) -> MODIFIED TO \(value)")
                })
            }
        }
```

I can retrieve the user but cannot save the changes as I am getting the following output error:

**2015-10-08 10:28:39.343 Hobbiester[11591:718652] [Error]: Caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException" with reason "User cannot be saved unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp":**

Comment: You'll need to update it from the server, or have a separate associated `reputation` object that other users can update.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work as designed.

Parse allows you to read other _user objects, but not to write to them. If you think about it, this makes sense from a security perspective. Otherwise you could modify passwords, email, name, etc. for other users. The client application will have to login as this user to make a change to that _user object.

https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#security-object-level-access-control

> ... The only exception is the _User class. We never allow users to write each other's data, but they can read it by default.

You could create another table in parse, perhaps a table of reputation modifications indexed by _users. Any user could write to that table. Then to get current reputation you query the modification table and add up all the changes. You could set it up so that all users have access to the new class in some manner that makes sense for your application. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer mentions, you cannot modify users that are not the current user, but you can create a cloud function and use  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
This would allow you to then query users and modify the objects.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("RemoveFollower", function(request, response){
var username = request.params.username_of_other_user;
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", username);
query.find({
success: function(results){
    var u = results[0];
    //u modify the user u however you like...
    u.save();
    response.success("Success");
},
error: function(){
    response.error("Error");
}
});
```